# How do I solve this ODE question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + y^2 - x^2$$
I tried to solve it using an integrating factor, but couldn't really get the answer.

Comment: the solution can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @jassie  There is a well known solution and it is:

$$y(x) = \frac{e^{x^2}}{c_1-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(x)}+x$$

Then we have to impose the initial condition $y(x) = x$ to fix the constant.

Comment: $\text{erfi}(x)$ is the imaginary error function. I doubt you have studied it in school. Are you sure that is the exercise you have to solve? (Or maybe you're at the University...)

Comment: yes i'm in university an i need to solve this

Comment: This is a non-linear ODE of the Riccati kind. Change of variable $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ to transforme it into a second order linear ODE not very difficult to solve for $u(x)$, if you know the special function erfi($x$).